# IONIC 4 - ngModel

Tags: ionic, ionic4

Quisiera saber como puedo poner en un console.log el texto "Material dañado", del ion-label

```
 <ion-label [(ngModel)]="value">Material dañado</ion-label>
```

Comment: Que tal Félix... El texto del ion-label es estático?? O de donde lo sacas??

Comment: Si, es estático, lo que quiero es poder utilizar el "Material dañado", para poder manejarlo mas fácil.
Ya sea cambiando el "value" o hacerlo de otra manera, pero no se realmente como hacerlo

Comment: intentaste con *document.getElementById()* y ponerle un *id* al elemento?? si es estático no deberías complicarte mucho con esto...